# How to get Message Text from ActiveMqMessage

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am a newbie to Apache ActiveMQ. From Producer I am sending following content:

```
{"senderPhNumber":"9986085716","sendingTime":"2015-07-20T22:11:24","spCode":"000001","customerName":"Vinod"}
```

Code from Producer

```
String text = messageStr;
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

// Tell the producer to send the message
System.out.println("Sent message: " + text );
producer.send(message);
```

From Consumer, the message is of type `ActiveMqMessage`. Consumer implements `MessageListener` and inside `onMessage()` I have the below code:

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg instanceof ActiveMQMessage){
        System.out.println("Inside If");
        try {
            ActiveMQMessage aMsg =  (ActiveMQMessage)msg;

            System.out.println( " Inside Listener ..." + aMsg);

            ProducerInfo prod = (ProducerInfo) aMsg.getDataStructure();
            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I print the message, it gets printed as below

> Received: ActiveMQMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false,
>   messageId = ID:AtulGupta-PC-50395-1437403689355-1:1:0:0:13,
>   originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId =
>   ID:AtulGupta-PC-50395-1437403689355-1:1:0:0, destination =
>   topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDelivered.Topic.atul, transactionId =
>   null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime =
>   1437403796470, brokerOutTime = 1437403796470, correlationId = null,
>   replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = Advisory, priority = 0,
>   groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed
>   = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@46347456, dataStructure =
>   ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = false,
>   messageId = ID:AtulGupta-PC-50417-1437403787762-3:1:1:1:1,
>   originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId =
>   ID:AtulGupta-PC-50417-1437403787762-3:1:1:1, destination =
>   topic://atul, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp =
>   1437403796468, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1437403796470,
>   brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent =
>   false, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0,
>   targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content =
>   null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null,
>   redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties
>   = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = null}, redeliveryCounter =
>   0, size = 0, properties =
>   {originBrokerId=ID:AtulGupta-PC-50395-1437403689355-0:1,
>   orignalDestination=ID:AtulGupta-PC-50417-1437403787762-3:1:1:1:1,
>   originBrokerName=localhost,
>   orignalMessageId=ID:AtulGupta-PC-50417-1437403787762-3:1:1:1:1,
>   originBrokerURL=tcp://AtulGupta-PC:61616}, readOnlyProperties = true,
>   readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer =
>   false}

How to retrieve the actual message content ?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but here's what I do (essentially). The point is to cast to `ActiveMQTextMessage` - not `ActiveMQMessage`.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof ActiveMQTextMessage) {
        ActiveMQTextMessage textMessage = (ActiveMQTextMessage) message;
        try {
            handleMessage(textMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("ActiveMQTextMessage handling failed", e);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.error("Message is not a text message " + message.toString());
    }
}

public static void handleMessage(ActiveMQTextMessage message) throws JMSException {
    try {
        String json = message.getText();
        DoSomethingWithJSON(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not extract data to log from TextMessage");
        throw e;
    }

    mongoClient.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting the message to a TextMessage and then get the message using getText() API.

You can refer to the code below in the link:
http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html

Comment: I have tried it, but when i try (message instanceof TextMessage) returns false.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet of how you receive the message at consumer side. It should work according to what you are saying.